# MVC Handled Error returns 200 on localhost but returns 500 on server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I use the code below to handle all unhandled errors on my controllers:

```
public abstract class BaseController: Controller
{
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

        if (IsJsonCall())
            filterContext.Result = HandleJsonError(filterContext.Exception);
        else
            filterContext.Result = HandleError(filterContext.Exception);
    }
}
```

In `HandleJsonError` function, I return a JSON object with information about the error. In my JavaScript code I detect this info and handle it properly.

Its working fine on localhost, returning a 200 HTTP Code to the client, but in my production environment, it returns the JSON object with the error info, so I can say its running all the code, but its returning a 500 HTTP code instead of 200, which is causing problems when JavaScript tries to recognize the returned content.

Why the codes returned are different event if the content is the same?

Comment: First of all you have to understand that the problem is with your server side code means your api. Secondly if code is same at both locations , local and server, then the environments could be different. Try remote dubgger tool in order to debug the production level app.

Comment: The error itself is not the problem, it was even handled and logged in my database, ,and I've already solved it. The question is why the server returns 500 and local returns 200, when the same error ocurrs on both environments, and the handling is executed on both too.